# What is the boost range of the sensor tower?

Tags: surviving-mars

When I put down a sensor tower and then scan squares nearby, how many squares away from that tower will I get a scanning speed boost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say without looking at the game code, as the actual radius is never shown.

From my experience:

- in the sector the tower is in: 400%
- adjacent sectors: 200-300%
- two sectors away: 40-120%
- further away: 10% (each sensor tower always gives a 10% boost no matter what sector you scan.)

Note, that the 10% boost stacks with other sensor towers. So, when you have 3 towers and build a new one, the sector the new tower is in will have 430% boost.